# Kohana 3.3 send parameter to default action

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana, kohana-3

I have an example controller called Home. The default method, set in the bootstrap is `action_index()`.
I also have a page that redirects to the url `127.0.0.1/home/123123` , where  123123 should be a parameter. But Kohana is actually trying to access a controller, named 123123. 
How can I set the route to `/home/[parameter]` ?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you need to redirect to is `127.0.0.1/home/index/123123` so that it knows the method you're wanting to use as well. It will only use the default  `action_index()` method if everything after `home/` is omitted.

You could potentially do it without the /index but you'd need some logic in the `before()` to check whether the parameter was === 'index' and then if not, store it as a variable and then run the index method manually.

The docs on [Routing](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing) may be of some help.